# Why did I get the U+2019 right single quotation mark not plain ASCII single quote in C mode?

Tags: character-encoding, quote, c-mode

In Emacs under C mode, why did the single quote key give me a U+2019 right single quotation mark, not a plain ASCII single quote? (That was corrected by a bot https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64104679/revisions)

Does the U+2019 right single quotation mark not work in C code?

In emacs:

- How can I tell, whether a single quote is a U+2019 right single quotation mark, or a plain ASCII single quote?
- How can I type U+2019 right single quotation mark and plain ASCII single quote respectively under emacs with C mode?
- How can I replace  U+2019 right single quotation mark with  plain ASCII single quote?

[image]